# Capturing Video on Mobile device using Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, air, flash-cs5, video-capture, air-native-extension

I am tasked with creating a video recording app for mobile devices (iPhone, iPad, Android) where the users are asked to record a short clip using their phones/tablets.

The video is then uploded to a server (either within the same app or a secondary app/site or via email)

Is it possible for an AIR app to record and save quality video and audio to the camera roll/gallery, or alternatively open the built-in video recorder app from the AIR app?

I am stuck between attempting this using Flash CS5.5 and deploy to iOS and Android using one code base, or building native apps and possibly duplicating my workload.

If I attempt the AIR route, will I hit problems with quality/resolution/usability etc? Or should I stick to building a native app? Time is of the essence too :)

I've done lots of research and not really found anything to swing my decision.

Thank in advance.

P